# Errors after requiring npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, electron

I'm trying to run an electron application on raspberry pi. When I use 
`var TJBot = require('tjbot')` in my code to import a node package, the following error occurs:

```
## There is an issue with `node-fibers` ##
`/Users/apple/app/node_modules/asyncawait/node_modules/fibers/bin/darwin-x64-53/fibers.node` is missing.

Try running this to fix the issue: /Users/apple/app/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron/
app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron Helper

/Users/apple/app/node_modules/
asyncawait/node_modules/fibers/build

Uncaught Error: Missing binary. See message above.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/app/node_modules/asyncawait/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:20:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/app/node_modules/asyncawait/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:26:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
```

If I remove this line or run it without using electron, everything works fine, so I'm not sure if this node library has a issue or it is caused by electron

Inside  `/Users/apple/app/node_modules/asyncawait/node_modules/fibers/bin/` I can see

```
darwin-ia32-46 darwin-x64-48  linux-ia32-48  repl           win32-x64-46
darwin-ia32-48 darwin-x64-51  linux-x64-46   win32-ia32-46  win32-x64-48
darwin-x64-46  linux-ia32-46  linux-x64-48   win32-ia32-48
```

Why do I need `darwin-x64-53` and where does it come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fibers is built to native binary code, it is not pure javascript. Rasperry Pi runs on ARM, which isn't included in the prebuilt binaries. The prebuilt binaries support 32 and 64 bit architectures for OSX (darwin), linux, and windows.

This means you need to manually build Fibers for your system, not install it via NPM. [The README for Fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/blob/master/README.md) has clear instructions on how to do so. I've included them here for ease of access. Please follow these instructions to try and get it running on Raspberry Pi / ARM.

#### Installing from source

- `git clone git://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers.git`
- `cd node-fibers`
- `npm install`

Note: node-fibers uses [node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) for
building. To manually invoke the build process, you can use `node-gyp rebuild`.
This will put the compiled extension in `build/Release/fibers.node`. However,
when you do `require('fibers')`, it will expect the module to be in, for
example, `bin/linux-x64-v8-3.11/fibers.node`. You can manually put the module
here every time you build, or you can use the included build script. Either
`npm install` or `node build -f` will do this for you. If you are going to be
hacking on node-fibers, it may be worthwhile to first do `node-gyp configure`
and then for subsequent rebuilds you can just do `node-gyp build` which will
be faster than a full `npm install` or `node-gyp rebuild`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Linux mint and I solved it as follows;
Based on [github source for node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) section about installing from the source;

```
git clone git://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers.git
cd node-fibers
npm install
```

Then I created a new directory;

```
mkdir /usr/local/lib/node_modules/iron-meteor/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-57/
```

Then I copied fibers.node to the newly created directory;

```
cp bin/linux-x64-57-glibc/fibers.node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/iron-meteor/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-57/
```

Then everything worked for me. You might have to adjust your permissions.